# Querying time lag in many-to-many table relationship

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of records in Table B (clinic visits) that occurred in the 6 months before any given event in Table A (survey administration). I am seeking advice about merging or relating these tables in R, and then querying them based on a date column:

Table A contains data on surveys that were administered to each study participant roughly every 6 months (though not the same admin date for each participant). This contains Participant ID and Survey Date, with a 4-5 unique dates for each participant ID:

```
PartID  SurveyDate
12  12/1/12
12  6/8/12
12  12/15/11
12  5/29/11
13  12/15/12
13  6/20/12
13  12/7/11
13  6/15/11
14  11/28/12
14  6/1/12
14  1/1/12
14  6/30/11
```

Additionally I have a table of clinic visits for each participant and their result (binary) for a certain disease test. Clinic visits occur throughout the year and may happen 0, 1, or many times between each survey administration. At each clinic visit, a test is done and the result is recorded at 1 if positive, 0 if negative.

```
     Part_ID Clinic_date Test_result
1        12     12/1/12          0
2        12    11/30/12          1
3        12      7/1/12          0
4        12      4/1/12          1
5        12    11/15/11          0
6        12     6/15/11          1
7        12      6/5/11          0
8        12      4/1/11          1
9        12    10/15/10          0
10       12    10/13/10          1
11       12     7/15/10          0
12       13    11/30/12          1
13       13      7/1/12          1
14       13      4/1/12          0
15       13    11/15/11          0
16       13     6/15/11          1
17       13      6/5/11          1
18       13      4/1/11          0
19       13    10/15/10          0
20       13    10/13/10          1
21       13     7/15/10          1
22       14    11/30/12          0
23       14      7/1/12          0
24       14      4/1/12          1
25       14    11/15/11          0
26       14     6/15/11          1
27       14      6/5/11          0
```

I would like to add a column to the survey administration table (table A) showing the number of positive clinic tests (1 in the Test_result column, co could use a sum) for that participant in the 6 months prior to the survey being given. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Read about [merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871) and maybe about `foverlaps()`. Please also add expected output.